# Convert directory with opus files to CSV or similar?

Tags: files, filenames, macos, file-metadata

I have a folder with opus sound files. I would like to convert that folder listing to something I can use in a spreadsheet. I want the result to contain something like file name, length of the sound and file size. How can this be done?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `exiftool -csv -- *.opus > list.csv` would get you almost there. Doesn't seem to include duration though.

Comment: Start with `man 1 ffprobe`:  *`DESCRIPTION:   ffprobe gathers information from multimedia streams and prints it in human- and machine-readable fashion.`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have recommended `exiftool` for that as it can extract metadata from most types of files and format it in csv:

```
exiftool -csv -FileSize -Duration -- *.opus > list.csv
```

But at least my version of `exiftool` doesn't seem to support extracting duration from opus files. As mentioned by @dodrg, `ffprobe` can though and also supports formatting its output as CSV:

```
{
  echo filename,duration,size
  for file in *.opus; do
  ffprobe -v warning \
          -of csv=p=0 \
          -show_entries format=filename,duration,size \
          -i "$file"
  done
} > list.csv
```

That's much slower though as it looks like `ffprobe` cannot return information from more than one file at a time, so we need to run one invocation per file.

Beware the order of the fields seems to be fixed. As in whether you specify `-show_entries format=filename,duration,size` or `-show_entries format=size,filename,duration`, the fields are always listed in `filename`, `duration`, `size` order.

You could also tell it to output everything in JSON format and reformat the information with the fields you want and in the order you want with `jq` and `mlr`. `mlr` can also help you join information returned by `exiftool` with information returned by `ffprobe`.

For example:

```
exiftool -csv -- *.opus |
  mlr --csv join --ijson -f <(
    for file in *.opus; do
      ffprobe -v warning -show_format -of json -i "$file"
    done | jq .format) -j SourceFile -l filename > list.csv
```

Add `then cut -f SourceFile,duration,size,Artist`... to the `mlr` command to restrict the output to the fields you're interested in.